# Escape # when rendering nested value via twig in Drupal 8

Tags: php, symfony, drupal, twig, drupal-8

In Drupal 8, when trying to render a nested value that starts with "#", such as #default_value, Symfony is freaking out because of the unescaped # that Drupal names it's array structures with. Is there a way to escape just the "#"?

I tried formatting it as raw and using the | e filter already without any luck.

```
<h1>Test</h1>
  <div>{{ form.field_perf_goal2_main.widget.0 }}</div>
  <div>
    {{ form.field_perf_goal2_main.widget.0.#default_value}}
  </div>
  {{ kint() }}
```

In the above example form.field_perf_goal2_main.widget.0 yields the correct result (when kinted).

form.field_perf_goal2_main.widget.0.#default_value throws an error of unexpected character. As far as I know there isn't an escape character feature in Twig.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `{{ form.field_perf_goal2_main.widget.0['#default_value'] }}`?

Comment: @pig-ball Well I'm feeling rather foolish for not thinking of that. If you answer I'm happy to mark as correct.

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pig-ball. Simply rendering it as such solved the issue.

```
{{ form.field_perf_goal2_main.widget.0['#default_value'] }}
```