# URL not rednering properly in JSON file

Tags: json

I have a JSON file that includes URL's. I have one that is giving me a problem. The URL breaks at the # tag. I have searched through the docs to no avail.

```
{
 
    "startDate": "2011,8,23",
 
    "headline": "First Scientific Integrity Committee Meeting",
 
    "text": "<img class='embedded' alt='' src='/system/files/styles/small/private/images/2022-02/stockpic.jpg?itok=gFJzkFW5'><br>The first Scientific Integrity Committee meeting occurred on August 23, 2011. The committee discussed the draft Policy, Scientific Integrity Program, and draft Committee Charter. After this initial meeting, the committee has continually met quarterly, if not more often. <a href=\https://www.epa.gov/scientific-integrity/scientific-integrity-epa#Scientific-integrity-committee\>Learn about the Scientific Integrity Committee.</a> </p>",
 
    "tag": "",
 
    "asset": {
 
      "media": "",
 
      "thumbnail": "",
 
      "credit": "",
 
      "caption": ""
 
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

BRuce

Comment: Show the actual JSON file entry.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: I don't see any `#` in the JSON, however.

Comment: It's in the URL. '<a href=\https://www.epa.gov/scientific-integrity/scientific-integrity-epa#Scientific-integrity-committee\>Learn about the Scientific Integrity Committee.</a>'

Comment: Now I see it in the edit. The problem isn't with the JSON itself, though, right? The JSON comes through fine (the `#` is not an escaping character in JSON). The problem you're having is using the URL in your source code, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: And in what language is your source code scripted in?

Comment: It's in a DRUPAL template. We are using the DRUPAL CMS. There is some JavaScript code that calls on the JSON file to render the slideshow.

Comment: I'd consider asking this in the Drupal stack exchange because I think it's a Drupal configuration issue because the `#` is non-escaping in HTML and JavaScript. I'll post some links that may be able to help you.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12589/views-escaping-special-characters-in-url

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/300174/how-do-i-include-special-characters-in-a-path-alias

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416848/escape-when-rendering-nested-value-via-twig-in-drupal-8

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help

Comment: Of course! Sorry I couldn't solve your problem! And thank you for your service!